# What is use of synchronized keyword?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what synchronized statement used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268016/what-synchronized-statement-used-for)

What is use of synchronized keyword?

Comment: ***Please*** search before you ask! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268016/what-synchronized-statement-used-for

Comment: You can also try some of these http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+synchronized+tutorial 2.1 million results including some tutorial videos

Answer (score 0):

This means that just one thread can execute that method.

Others threads which call it will wait until another finish the execution. Then the next start executing it.